# I can't change variable colors One Dark Pro Visual Studio Code for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm having an issue regarding Visual Studio Code OneDark Pro theme. I would like to change the color of variables (only variables I declare, not method calls, etc. but when I try to do this using

```json
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "scope": "source.python",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#E06C75"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

I get this (I wrote a code sample to illustrate what is happening):

[image]

As you can see, colons are in red, every variables even the "for i in..." and the full "os.system.getcwd()" are in red.

I only want the variables I declare to be in red. How can I do that ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: do they have different textmate scopes?

Comment: I don't think so unforunately...

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the editor color in VSCode with `Syntax Highlighting` like this:

```
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "variables": "#c3e01f"
      },
```

Or the `Semantic Highlighting` like this:

```
  "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[The Theme Name]": {
      "rules": {
        "variable.declaration": "#c3e01f"
      }
  }
},
```

If you don't know the scope of the object which you want to customize, you can use the built-in tool in VSCode: `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`(Command Palette).

And I think [this article](https://medium.com/@danromans/how-to-customize-semantic-token-colorization-with-visual-studio-code-ac3eab96141b) and [this one](https://www.alveeakand.com/how-to-modify-themes-in-vscode/) can help you understand the color customization in the VSCode.

Comment: @Roux Which part do you want to customize in your example code?

Comment: only the variable declaration

Comment: @Roux Could you declare a variable only, such as f="test". And post a screenshot of the settings.json file and the python file?